# How to get the exact percentage in a JavaScript formula

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out what will be the JavaScript formula if I have a data in my database and this is i want to be the output:

- if the data = 10 I want to be output that in a 100% in which I will be going to use in an div element height
- if the data = 65 I want to be output that in a 0% in which I will be going to use in an div element height

and this is my code right now but I can't figure it out:

```
   var datas = JSON.parse(data);
             var ID, Bio, Non_Bio, Recy, Extra;
             var div = 10;

              ID = datas[0].ID;
              Bio = datas[0].Bio;
              Non_Bio = datas[0].Non_Bio;
              Recy = datas[0].Recy;
              Extra = datas[0]. Extra;

             var obtained = Bio;  
             var obtained2 = Non_Bio;
             var obtained3 = Recy;


             var obt = obtained*100/div;
             var obt2 = obtained2*100/div;
             var obt3 = obtained3*100/div;

             var water1 =   $("#water1").height() + obt;
             var water2 =   $("#water2").height() + obt2;
             var water3 =   $("#water3").height() + obt3;
```

Comment: What about any values in between? Should they be proportional? For example `data = 37.5` will result in `50%`?

Comment: are you able to fetch data from db?and store it in the variables defined? and what about below 65 value? and between 65-100??

Comment: Can you reword the second two sentences to make their meaning  clearer in English?

Comment: the ultrasonic sensor trows only integer value

Comment: @AyushiKeshri yes i was able to fetch data from db my only problem is when the sensor throws value of 10 i want to display that on a css value height of 100% but i cant get the exact formula on how to do that same as when the value if 65 the css value height should be 0% like that

Comment: @traktor53  when the sensor throws value of 10 i want to display that on a css value height of 100% and when the ultrasonic sensor throws value of 65 the css value height should be 0% like that coz my project is monitoring the trashbins and i would to display the level of the bins on a system using an ultrasonic sensor

Answer (score 0):

```js
var datas=[{
    ID :10,
    Bio :7,
    Non_Bio: 65,
    Recy :75,
    Extra :20
}]
var obt=[];
datas.map((data,index)=>{
    console.log(data)
Object.values(data).map(item=>{
        console.log(item)
    if(item===10){
        obt.push("100%");
      }
      else{
        obt.push("0%");
      }
     
})})
console.log("required output:");
console.log(obt);
```

Assumed:  ID = datas[0].ID; since you are fetching from array 0th index and then its key.It mus be array of object (you have not given the proper inputs.) and the if logic can be changed accordingly as you mentioned if its 10 it must be 100%.

Logic: Just iterating each object of the array and then getting the object values (of each key i.e. id,bio etc..) and checking the value if divisible by 10 then pushing that data into empty array so you can use it further. You can also insert the output data into map.

Comment: hmmm maybe this will work but it could be a lot of code im just trying to figure out the exact formula coz im displaying like a trashbin design on my system that will see what percentage of the garbage on that trashbin something like that

Comment: @john  can you please provide other inputs rather than just saying if its 10 then 100% bcz thats just if and else code.I have here also corrected the way you are fetching the data and using lots of variables in the code.This is much optimized code rather than what you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If the math can't be solved in one's head, doing it on paper can help, particularly when solving a pair of simultaneous equations using high school maths.

Assuming the ultrasound value to height relationship is linear you can write it as the equation of a line:

```
    h = a * u + b    ... 1)
```

where `h` is height, `u` is the ultrasound sensor reading, and `a` and `b` are constants.

Now take two calibration values of sensor readings taken for an empty and a full bin and call them `c0` and `c100` respectively.

From 1)

```
  0  = a * c0 + b    ... 2) using the c0 value , and 
100  = a * c100 + b  ... 3) using c100
```

Solving this pair of simultaneous equations proceeds along the lines of

```
  b = 0 -a*c0          ... from 2)
  b = 100 -a*c100      ... 4) from 3)
  Hence
  0 -a*c0 = 100 -a*c100
  a*c100 - a*c0 = 100
  a = 100/(c100-c0)    ... 5)
```

and now substituting 4) back into 2) gives

```
  b = 100 - a*c100   ... 6)
```

In this test example, the equations are converted into a factory function that returns an object with calibrate and height functions  `calibrate(c0, c100)` and `height( sensor)`. The height returned is rounded to the nearest quarter due to an overall lack of precision in the data.

```js
function createBin() {
    var a, b;
    function calibrate( c0, c100) {
        a = 100/(c100-c0);
        b = 100 - a*c100;
    }
    function height( sensor) {
        let h = a * sensor + b;
        return Math.round( 4*h)/4;
    }
    return {calibrate, height};
}
    
const bin = createBin();
bin.calibrate (65, 10);

var readings = [67, 65, 37, 10, 5];
readings.forEach(
    reading =>  console.log( "height( %s) = %s%", reading, bin.height(reading))
);
```

Note that when dealing with real world sensors, calibration data can vary between sensors and installations - hard coding equations that need to be calibrated against hardware variability is something to be avoided.